# Read and copy file with EOF indicator in the middle

Tags: c++, c, file-io, eof

I used the code below to copy from one binary file to another, but the first file contains some EOF indicators (0xFF) as part of it, so the copy function actually copies the file until its first EOF indicator.

For example: if my file is `{0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0xFF, 0x01, 0x02, 0xFF, 0xFF}` then only `{0x01, 0x02, 0x03}` will be copied to the new file. Any idea how to fix it (or maybe I'm missing something there...)

Code:

```
int Util_Copy_File(char* source, char* dest)
{
    FILE *fs,*ft;  
    char ch;
    char infile[100];
    sprintf(infile, "%s", dest);
    fs = fopen(infile,"r");  
    if(fs==NULL)  
    {
        return -1;  
    }
    ft = fopen(dest,"w");  
    if(ft==NULL)  
    {  
    fclose(fs);  
    return STATUS_FAIL;
    }  

    while(1)  
    {  
    ch = getc(fs);  
    if(ch==EOF)  
    {  
        break;  
    }  
    else  
        putc(ch,ft);  
    } 
    fclose(fs);  
    fclose(ft);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks,
Binyamin

Comment: You need to open the file as `binary` ("rb").  Some operating systems may treat non-ASCII chars as an EOF.  For example, Windows treats 0x1A as EOF when reading in text mode.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

fgetc returns an int, not a char , so you can tell the difference between EOF and a char with the same value as EOF.

Change:

```
char ch;
```

to

```
int ch
```

And (usually not relevant if you're on *nix)

```
fs = fopen(infile,"r");
```

to

```
fs = fopen(infile,"rb");
```

Comment: Right, and since it's a binary file also change the `fopen()` of the destination file to `fopen(dest,"wb")`

Comment: It even has a wikipedia (sub-)page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getchar#EOF_pitfall

Comment: That, or even better use `fread` and `fwrite` to read and write more than one byte in one go.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. After all I did miss something ;)

Answer (score 1):

`0xFF` is not `EOF`. -1 is `EOF`. The problem is that you're storing the `int` return value of `getc` in a `char`, which collapses `0xFF` onto -1 (actually it's implementation-defined behavior but that's what common implementations will do).

The return value of `getc` is an `int` whose value is either in the range of `unsigned char` or `EOF` (which has value -1). And the correct type for binary data is `unsigned char`, not `char`.