# about getchar function in C

Tags: c

I am reading K & R C language book, following code fragment:

```
char c;
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) ...
```

It was mentioned that for EOF (i think it is -1) is an "out of band" return value from getchar, distinct from all possible
values that getchar can return.

My questions are following:

1. I ran my program with char and it ran successfully, and my
   understanding is `signed char` can store -127 to +127 so it can check
   for -1 how it is "out of band" ?
2. Can any one provide simple example where above program fragment will fail if we use `char c` instead of `int c`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You have a small mistake, `getchar` returns an `int`, not a `char`:

```
int c;
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) ...
```

The valid values for ascii chars are from 0 to 127, the EOF is some other (int) value.

If you keep using `char`, you might get into troubles (as [I got into](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3866075/read-and-copy-file-with-eof-indicator-in-the-middle))

Comment: The value range for *ASCII* is indeed 0–127, but it actually returns bytes (0–255). From the man page: *Character values are returned as an unsigned char converted to an int.  If the stream is at end-of-file or a read error occurs, the routines return EOF.*

Comment: True, yet the EOF value might be an int value and not a char value.

Comment: It *is* an int value and that's the point: the "in-band" value range is 0-255, but the "out-of-band" EOF is usually -1 and thus cannot be mistaken for an in-band value. You could also define EOF as being 256 or any other not-in-band-value :-)

Answer (score 5):

Well, your question is answered in the [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/stdio/getcharc.html).

> Two failure modes are possible if, as in the fragment above, getchar's
>   return value is assigned to a char.
>
> - If type char is signed, and if `EOF` is defined (as is usual) as -1, 
>     the character with the decimal value 255 ('\377' or '\xff' in C) will 
>     be sign-extended and will compare equal to EOF, prematurely
>     terminating the input.
> - If type char is unsigned, an actual `EOF` value will be truncated (by
>     having its higher-order bits discarded, probably resulting in 255 or  `0xff`) and will not be recognized as `EOF`, resulting in effectively infinite input.

Comment: @Jesus Ramos The C FAQ is awesome :-)

Comment: Definitely. Contains all the little things you sometimes don't think about.

Comment: Since the standard 7.19.1 says EOF is int with a negative value. Should I consider @venkysmarty 's code would fail **if and only if** EOF<-128 OR the type char is unsigned?

Comment: @Stan I'm not sure if these are all the cases that would bring problems but in general if `EOF` *can* be stored by a `char` it should be ok.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever value EOF has depends on your platform. Take a look at stdio.h too see its actual definition.

Comment: EOF cannot be 0. While it doesn't have to be -1, it does have to be negative (C99, §7.19.1/3).